# Questions on summatory function related to non-integer-powers

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, riemann-hypothesis

Consider the summatory function

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x 1_{n\ne k^m}\tag{1}$$

where $1_{n\ne k^m}$ is the non-integer-power indicator function which returns $1$ when $n$ is a non-integer-power and $0$ otherwise. In order for $n$ to be considered a non-integer-power there must be a difference in at least one of the exponents in the prime factorization of $n=p_1^{e_1}\,p_2^{e_2}\,...\,p_r^{e_r}$ (i.e. $e_1\,...\,e_r$ must not all have the same value).

---

Here's a list of non-integer powers for $1\le n\le 100$.

$$\{12,18,20,24,28,40,44,45,48,50,52,54,56,60,63,68,72,75,76,80,84,88,90,92,96,98,99\}\tag{2}$$

---

The discrete plot of $f(x)$ illustrated in Figure (1) below illustrates the asymptotic for $f(x)$ seems to be nearly a linear function. In Figure (1) below $f(x)$ is evaluated at intervals of $100$ for a total of $100$ plot points.

[image: Illustration of f(x) defined in formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $f(x)$ defined in formula (1)

---

**Question (1)**: Does the Riemann hypothesis predict a bound on the growth of $f(x)$?

---

**Question (2)**: Can the Dirichlet series defined in formula (3) below be expressed in terms of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$?

$$F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1_{n\ne k^m}}{n^s}\tag{3}$$

Comment: I noticed OEIS entry A059404 seems to be related to my question see https://oeis.org/A059404).

Comment: It is immediate that $x-f(x)= \sum_{n\le x}|\mu(n)|+\sum_{k\ge 2} \sum_{1 < n\le x^{1/k}}|\mu(n)|=\frac6{\pi^2}x+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$. Not sure about the improvement of the remainder.

Comment: Did you mean the $e_i$ must be coprime? The $e_i$ for $k^m$ ($k$ and $m$ integers, $m>1$) need not be equal; for example the powers of 12.

Comment: @RosieF You're right my two definitions seem inconsistent. I think I should have added that $k$ has to be square-free (i.e. k=rad(n)).